# word limits on multiple text areas

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, textarea

I am creating a website with four textarea forms. Each form has a word limit.

- textarea1: 250 word limit
- textarea2: 500 word limit
- textarea3: 500 word limit
- textarea4: 250 word limit

I have tried using existing examples that I have found when trying to fix this problem but nothing seems to work.

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var maxwords = 250;
//
function check_length(obj, cnt, rem)
{
    var ary = obj.value.split(" "); // doubled spaces will throw this off
    var len = ary.length;
    cnt.innerHTML = len;
    rem.innerHTML = maxwords - len;
    if (len > maxwords) {
        alert("Message in '" + obj.name + "' limited to " + maxwords + " words.");
        ary = ary.slice(0,maxwords-1);
        obj.value = ary.join(" "); // truncate additional words
        cnt.innerHTML = maxwords;
        rem.innerHTML = 0;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
} 

</script>
```

HTML

```
   <textarea name="Message 1" onkeypress="
 return check_length(this,
 document.getElementById('count1'),
 document.getElementById('remaining1'));"></textarea>
Word count: <span id="count1">0</span> &nbsp;
Words remaining: <span id="remaining1">250</span>

<textarea name="Message 2" onkeypress="
 return check_length(this,
 document.getElementById('count2'),
 document.getElementById('remaining2'));"></textarea>
Word count: <span id="count2">0</span> &nbsp;
Words remaining: <span id="remaining2">500</span>
```

Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance,
Tom

Comment: can we see your attempts on a fiddle?

Comment: I think `maxlength` can be applied to text-areas too.

Comment: you might have to create a function that takes the textbox input and uses the space delimiter to see how many words are in the textbox. this method would be require to run on an interval or some other updating system(maybe on spacebar) that would allow you to update everytime. it might be worth it to go for a character limit rather than a word limit.

Comment: updated my post with the code i am currently using

Comment: you ask us to solve the problem but you don't even suggest what the problem could be or what errors your running into. does it call the function? is it counting the words but not updating correctly? try to debug a bit first and tell us what errors you run into.

Comment: the problem I am having is that the first form with 250 word limit works, but i dont know how to allow the second form to have a different word limit (500 words)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an extra parameter to your function, and send it the maxWords from each function call:

```
function check_length(obj, cnt, rem, maxwords)
{
//... rest of the function would stay the same
```

and when you call it, include the max words

```
<textarea name="Message 2" onkeypress="
 return check_length(this,
 document.getElementById('count2'),
 document.getElementById('remaining2'), 250);"></textarea>
Word count: <span id="count2">0</span> &nbsp;
Words remaining: <span id="remaining2">500</span>
```

To remove the words remaining,

```
function check_length(obj, cnt, maxwords)
{
    var ary = obj.value.split(" "); // doubled spaces will throw this off
    var len = ary.length;
    cnt.innerHTML = len;

    if (len > maxwords) {
        alert("Message in '" + obj.name + "' limited to " + maxwords + " words.");
        ary = ary.slice(0,maxwords-1);
        obj.value = ary.join(" "); // truncate additional words
        cnt.innerHTML = maxwords;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

and in your HTML,

```
<textarea name="Message 1" onkeypress="
return check_length(this,
document.getElementById('count1'),250);"></textarea>
Word count: <span id="count1">0</span> &nbsp;
```

Comment: do you know if there is a way to remove the 'word count' and just have the 'words remaining'? If i remove 
'Word count: <span id="count2">0</span>'
then none of it works.
thanks again

Comment: you'd have to also remove the references to it in your function, since the function is looking for that element and if it is not in the DOM, it will throw an error. I will update my answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your function is that you're always checking the amount of words inserted against `maxwords` variable (which is set to 250 words as the first textarea limit)

so a better attempt is to pass an extra parameter to the function with the original limit (different for each textarea)

Comment: thanks for the reply, im not that great at javascript, so how would i pass an extra parameter?

Comment: mike's answer could be a valid example

Answer (score 0):

insert a `class` attribute for those textareas, (like `class='area250'`, `class='area500'` and so on) then include an if statement in the function

```
function check_length(obj, cnt, rem)
    {
        if(window.event.srcElement.getAttribute('class')=='area250')
            maxwords=250;
        else if(window.event.srcElement.getAttribute('class')=='area500')
            maxwords=500;
        else .......................................

    }
```