# Limit pasted words in multiple text area fields?

Tags: javascript, textarea, word-count

I'm a complete novice in JavaScript, so please forgive my ignorance. I've worked on this for several days, but it's beyond my skill level.

Please, could someone help me implement into this specific script: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11228092, something that limits words in each text area when **pasted**, too?

The script limits correctly when typing, but pasting sneaks past the word limit. To emphasize for clarity, I do mean counting words rather than characters.

I've tried looking at other methods, but they either limit characters rather than words, don't seem to apply to multiple, differing teaxtarea fields, or I just don't understand enough to implement them properly.

Thanks for any help anyone can give!

Comment: You could bind your function to the paste event, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10833836/paste-event-in-javascript

Comment: Also on a side note, you should *always* avoid using HTML events like `onkeypress` and instead create event listeners and attach them to DOM elements.

Comment: Thanks, both of you! I am reading about binding the function to the paste event, and creating event listeners. The problem I'm facing is that I'm so new and unschooled, I don't even have the JS/JQ vocabulary to know what these terms mean, or how to implement them. The topics & link are very helpful for research items though, thank you!